# Both shower heads have less flow after water heater replacement

Tags: plumbing

Just had professional replacement of 50gal water heater. Both Shower heads in master bath have noticeable lower pressure than before. Plumber used CPvC on new installation connected to existing copper. Could there be diameter difference causing a restriction and how do I tell?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you turn on one shower head, and then turn on the other, does the first one's pressure significantly decrease?

Comment: If you edit your post to include a picture (or load a picture to imgur, edit your post to include the link, and someone will edit to get the picture itself in there) showing the CPVC to copper join, including pipes on both sides, it may be obvious whether size is a likely issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest removing both showerheads (and all your faucet aerators, as well, perhaps) to check for debris - major work like changing a water heater often dislodges  crud in the lines that ends up clogging the point of exit, so cleaning and backflushing is needed to restore flow. While you have them off, run the shower full bore from the bare pipes for a while to remove any additional crud you can. Don't know if I think a good pro plumber should have done this, or if the average customer would complain about the extra half and hour at plumbers rates for doing it...

As for the size of the lines, you should be able to read the size right off the side of the CPVC - possibly the copper as well, though that's a bit closer to intuitive to measure, and it's probably too old to be easily readable even if it is printed on.

Answer (score 0):

They might have not fully opened a valve after the work was finished. Check any valves to ensure they are fully open.